# Print the prime numbers in each range of 10 on a separate line

Tags: c

I want to separate the output (the printing) of the program for each 10 inputs. The code is to find the prime numbers from 1 to n and the median of them.

I just want to separate the print for each 10 counts of n like:

```
primes from  1 to 10:
       from 10 to 20:
       from 20 to 30:
```

Can you help me doing it please?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, x, y, p, sum, sumx;
    float arm;
    sum = 0, sumx = 0;
    printf("\n Enter the maximum value of n =");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n All prime numbers from 1 to %d are: ", n);

    for (x = 2; x <= n; x++)
    {
        p = 1;
        for (y = 2; y <= x / 2; y++)
        {
            if (x % y == 0)
            {
                p = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (p == 1)
        {
            sum += x;
        }
        if (p == 1 && x != 1)
        {
            printf("%d ", x);
            sumx++;
            arm = (sum * 1.0) / sumx;
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe sum of all Prime numbers from 1 to %d =%d", n, sum);
    printf("\nTotal prime numbers is %d", sumx);
    printf("\nThe median of all Prime numbers from 1 to %d is %.2f", n, arm);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41406094/edit) your question and add that information.

Comment: Try to explain more.

Comment: It is fortunate for you that there are no primes that end in 0 so the overlapping ranges (1..10 overlaps with 10..20) do not present a problem.  You have to arrange to output newlines every so often.  The range 200..210 is the first range from `x*10 .. (x+1)*10` without any primes (but 199 and 211 are prime); do you expect to produce a blank line for that empty decade?  Note that the median is the middle number in sorted order — you seem to be computing the mean, not the median.

Comment: The check for `x != 1` in ` if(p==1&&x!=1)` seems to be a leftover from an earlier version of the code; the outer loop starts with `x = 2` and `x` is only incremented, so the condition `x != 1` is always true.

Comment: Please do not show screenshots for pure text output. You can copy&paste the text into your question and improve readability.

Comment: `from 10 to 20:` --> `from 11 to 20:` ? because `from 10 to 20:` has 11 counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could print out "From _ to _:" whenever you reach a value of x divisible by 10:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, x, y, p, sum, sumx;
    float arm;
    sum = 0, sumx = 0;
    printf("\n Enter the maximum value of n =");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n All prime numbers from 1 to %d are: ", n);
    int upper = n < 10? n : 10;
    printf("\nFrom 1 to %d: ", upper);

    for (x = 2; x <= n; x++)
    {
        p = 1;
        for (y = 2; y <= x / 2; y++)
        {
            if (x % y == 0)
            {
                p = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (p == 1)
        {
            sum += x;
        }
        if (p == 1 && x != 1)
        {
            printf("%d ", x);
            sumx++;
            arm = (sum * 1.0) / sumx;
        }

        if (x % 10 == 0 && x != n) {
            int upper = (x + 10) > n? n : (x + 10);
            printf("\nFrom %d to %d: ", x + 1, upper);
        }   
    }

    printf("\nThe sum of all Prime numbers from 1 to %d =%d", n, sum);
    printf("\nTotal prime numbers is %d", sumx);
    printf("\nThe median of all Prime numbers from 1 to %d is %.2f", n, arm);

    return 0;
}
```

This would result in an output like this:

> Enter the maximum value of n =29
>
> All prime numbers from 1 to 29 are:
>
> From 1 to 10: 2 3 5 7
>
> From 11 to 20: 11 13 17 19
>
> From 21 to 29: 23 29
>
> The sum of all Prime numbers from 1 to 29 =129
>
> Total prime numbers is 10
>
> The median of all Prime numbers from 1 to 29 is 12.90

Comment: yeah thats the output i want put can u give me the full code :)
im a kind of beginner 
Thx

Comment: Bimki, Done. Pasted the other parts as-is from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question clearly but if you want to separate lines for prime numbers ranging between 10 to 20 or 20 to 30 then you can add this inside your loop

```
if(x%10 == 0)
    printf("\n");
```

Or, if you want to you want 10 prime number in a line then

```
if(sumx%10 == 0)
    printf("\n");
```